# giving username sql server 2012 management studio

Tags: sql-server

I am installing SQL Server 2012 and I have selected to install Default instance. and authentication type is mixed but I don't want to add default username as    "as" , I want give different username.

Is is Possible??
Give me suggestion how to achieve it

Comment: Create a new account & disable *sa*

Comment: @AlexK. thanks am going with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean the SA? 
If so... you can add your own administrators (ideally with windows authentication) and add them to the role sysadmin. After that you can give SA a very strong password and deactivate it afterwards. The strong password is recommended, as even if the sa is accidentally or by an exploit is available, the password will give a little bit better protection.